# problem migrating files from https to http mock site - how to see mock site

Tags: migration, https

I used a migration/backup plugin to grab the files from a secured site to my mock up site that is not secured.  Since I'm not using it for anything other than adding some functionality to it - no members, no sales of products, I didn't think of any trouble going from https to http but now I get the old

> SSL connection error 
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
>   message.

All the files are on the site.

What files do I need to edit so I can see the site?

Thanks.

Comment: What migration/backup plugin did you use? Have you made sure there are no SSL flags in your `wp-config.php`? And that you have set `siteurl` and `home` in your options table to the non-ssl URL (or define them in your config, which override the database).

Comment: Used wp migrate d but didn't think of the certificate issue until after I'd made the migration. When I checked the wp-config file the only mentions of https were api wordpress to get new salts and then wordpress codex.  Nothing else.  I can't get in to the backend to check the settings since I'm getting the error.  Is there another way to sneak in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot get access to the website due to a HTTP/HTTPS conflict, you need to ensures that all of the URLs for your website are up-to-date, try the following steps using the [Search Replace DB tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/):

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://example.com/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.